# Android-StackExchange Swag?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Looking through the [StackExchange Store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/), I didn't see any stuff for the Android site. Are there any plans for swag (t-shirts, mugs, etc) for android.stackexchange? If not, how can we start this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do generate site-specific t-shirts and stickers, as you can see here:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/

but this site isn't quite at the correct place in its lifecycle for that to happen.

Soon!